# Не могу настроить mysql

Tags: mysql, macos, root, homebrew

Поставил mysql с помощью brew. Столкнулся с проблемами.

1)ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

2) при обращении к mysql он выдает ошибку: mysql_install_db: command not found. Не смотря на то, что mysql.server start работает.

3)Команда: sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
  Ошибка:sudo: /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server: command not found
 В интернете советуют прописать переменные окружения. Не помогает. Вообще даже при попытке смены пароля, не получается обратиться к ней никак. Когда пытался прописать переменные окружения сломал себе все остальные. Не работал ни brew ни npm ни go.

Прошу помощи с настройкой mysql именно через brew. Желательно дать полную инструкцию и по установке, и по настройке пароля. Так как промежуточные варианты из интернета не помогают.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: через консоль получается подключиться? `mysql -uroot`. Попробуйте удалить полностью с настройками mysql и установить его заново. `brew remove mysql*`

Comment: Уверенны что mysql server у вас находится по тому пути что вы пытаетесь запустить? И если он работает, то можно посмотреть где лежит файл в процессах

Comment: @Ninazu конечно же я пробовал переустановить, так же я знаю что по дефолту он должен ставиться в этот путь. Но его почему то там нет. А все инсрукции в инетике ведут именно по этому пути.

Comment: Ну так поищите, где он у вас лежит. Благо поиск есть для таких дел. Ну и на всякий случай в папочку `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/` загляньте, обычно brew туда ставит

Comment: хорошо. то есть если я буду обращаться к этой папке все по идее должно заработать?

Comment: @Ninazu а как решить проблему с ошибкой 1045?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81043/discussion-between-ninazu-and-gleb-nazemnov).